# Display value as a link

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using oracle APEX 19.2.

In interactive report i have list of value in one column, so is it possible to Display value using as a link to the page and how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the values in the list of values supposed to be the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'f?p='||:APP_ID||':3(page number on which to redirect ):'||:APP_SESSION||'::::variable_name:'||variable_value
```

variable_name = variable on page where you want to redirect.

variable_value = value for above variable. (can be set to report column value)

You can simply add something like above in your column (`SQL` script) which you want to work as link. Then set column type as link under Identification. Add #COLUMN_NAME# (with hash) in link text under Link.

All of this will be available after you select respective column under that report in page designer.

To understand URL better use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017).

Answer (score 1):

Click on your column select type = link and change the option scape characters to no and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link outside

For the column you want to use to link outside change

```
Identification -> Type to Value: Link
```

And then it's possible to define

```
Link -> Target : Page n
```